# Singular screen scrolling with two fragments (Fragment and ListFragment)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listfragment

I have an activity that sometimes displays two fragments with one directly on top of another. The top fragment contains just a few TextViews and is fine. The lower is a ListFragment with its own layout populated using a SimpleCursorAdapter.

The problem is that the lower fragment scrolls independently of everything else so the top fragment is always visible. I'd like the entire screen to scroll instead.

I have tried a static fragment inside the top's layout (which leads to other problems), adjusting FrameLayout to Linear/Relative, and nested fragments to no avail. The best I've gotten is to hard-code a height for the lower fragment (e.g. 1000dp) which then changes the scrolling behavior at least. Unfortunately that's not a usable solution. I know the top level RelativeLayout in the main layout needs to be in a , but that doesn't solve the ListFragment nested scrolling issue.

Both fragments function great on their own, it's when I display them both that the problem arises.

Is there some way I can force my ListFragment to display all its data in a non-scrollable manner so that I can make the entire main screen scroll as one?

The current main layout, **activity_main.xml**, is :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/container_toolbar"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/container_bottom"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="activity.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The second (ListFragment) layout, **fragment_calculations_list**, is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/listview_row"
    android:background="@drawable/border_style"
    android:id="@+id/calclist">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_m_d"
        android:text="05.23"
        style="@style/listview_row_left_top"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_below="@id/date_m_d"
        style="@style/listview_row_left_bottom"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/date_m_d"
        style="@style/listview_row_right_top" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value_detail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/value"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/date_m_d"
        style="@style/listview_row_right_bottom" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value_detail2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/value"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/value_detail"
        style="@style/listview_row_right_bottom_second" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Since it's referenced (removed unnecessary stuff like colors)

```
<style name="listview_row">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

The ListFragment adapter is set in onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        pID = getArguments().getInt("id");
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Referenced without valid id");
    }

    String[] selectArgs = {Integer.toString(pID)};
    super.query = "myqueryhere";
    super.queryArgs = myArgs;

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_calculations_list, current,
            new String[] {
                "fielda","fieldb", "fieldc", "fieldd", "fielde"
            },
            new int[] {R.id.date_m_d, R.id.title, R.id.value, R.id.value_detail, R.id.value_detail2},
        0);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    if (current==null) {
        db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "my.db", 1);
        task=new LoadCursorTask().execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would take me a while to set up an example to determine for sure what would work, but I have a couple ideas that you might want to look into trying:

- Instead of using a SimpleCursorAdapter for the ListFragment, check into using a [HeaderViewListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.html). I've never used one of these so I can't really tell you how to set up the headerViewInfos ArrayList, but the description sounds like what you want if you can figure out how to use it.
- You could look into combining the fragments in a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html). Although I don't know how well this will work with a ListFragment, but it's something you could try.

So that's not really a definitive answer, but it's a couple avenues you could go down so you're not at a dead end if no one else answers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried the ScrollView approach but that doesn't seem to play nicely with ListFragments. I found a few vague references to similar problems that seemed to validate the problems are with the class itself.

That HeaderViewListAdapter looks promising. I think it's worth a shot too, I haven't used one of those before either.